# Visual Studio Code- Debugging in c# isn't Starting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've installed VSC and the extension for c# (powered by OmniSharp).
I click on "Start Debugging" and it asks me for my debugging environment, I click on .Net Core and then nothing happens.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: are you in release mode?

Comment: What do you mean? where can I check that?

Comment: take a look at this link, Im just re-installing this now and will get a better answer for you in a moment https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: ignore my previous comment, thats not in there....  can you send me some sample of the code your trying to debug and i will see if i get the same issue

Comment: This is just an assignment (var p=4;)

Comment: have you only got the one line in VSC?

Comment: whats the environment set as?

Comment: are you still having the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Save your file as a C# file and that should download an OmniSharp package and the .Net core debugger.

Once you have all that you can then press F9 on the line you want and then youll be able to debug as you like 
[image]

Comment: The file is already saved as such (try both with csx and cs files).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and all I needed to do was restart VSCode to get it working again. I think that OmniSharp was having some issues and restarting VSCode allows it to get back up and running again.